# Calling a function from outside of Reactjs class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fairly new to Reactjs and am running into an issue. I am using Griddle to display my data and using a Custom Component as a Column Definition. This custom component is defined outside of the class that contains the Griddle render and contains two buttons - Delete and Edit. I need to be able to click on either button and launch a modal, which I am using React Modal for. If I put a button within the class I can launch the modal as expected, however, when I am trying to launch the modal from one of the Edit or Delete buttons it does not work and I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: M.handleOpenModal is not a function.
```

[image]
[image]

Here is the code for the component that uses the Griddle plugin:

```
const actionComponent = ({ value }) =>
<div>
    <a href={`/LinerReads/Details/${value}`} className="btn btn-warning"><i className="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="#" onClick={handleModalOpen} data-id={value} className="btn btn-danger"><i className="fas fa-times"></i> Delete</a>
</div>

const handleModalOpen = function () {
    LinersTable.handleOpenModal();
}

export default class LinersTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { liners: [], station: '', loading: true, selectedRowId: 0 };
        this.modalElement = React.createRef();

        this.options = {
            defaultSortName: 'title',  // default sort column name
            defaultSortOrder: 'desc'  // default sort order
        };
    }
handleOpenModal() {
    alert();
}

render() {
    let contents = this.state.loading ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p> : this.renderLinersTable(this.state.liners);

    return <div>
        <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={() => { this.refreshData() }}>Refresh</button>
        <a href="LinerReads/Studio" className='btn btn-primary'>Studio View</a>
        <a href="LinerReads/Add" className='btn btn-primary'>Add</a>
        <LinersStations onChange={this.handleStationChange.bind(this)} />
        <ModalWindow ref={this.modalElement} />
        {contents}
    </div>;
}

renderLinersTable(liners) {
    return (
        <Griddle
            styleConfig={styleConfig}
            data={liners}
            plugins={[plugins.LocalPlugin]}
            components={{ Layout: NewLayout }}>
            <RowDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition id="title" title="Title" order={1} width={600} />
                <ColumnDefinition id="startDateString" title="Start" order={2} width={200} />
                <ColumnDefinition id="endDateString" title="End" order={3} width={200} />
                <ColumnDefinition id="linerID" title="Actions" customComponent={actionComponent} width={200} />
            </RowDefinition>
        </Griddle>
    )
}
}
```

I have tried moving the Custom Component inside the class

```
handleModalOpen = function () {
        this.handleOpenModal();
    }

    handleOpenModal() {
        alert();
    }
```

but it then throws an error

```
ReferenceError: handleModalOpen is not defined

Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: handleModalOpen is not defined
```

Anyone have a suggestion as to what I am missing or doing incorrect?

Comment: Why you want to move the function `handleModalOpen` inside class LinersTable ?

Comment: You can't call the function like LinersTable.handleOpenModal(); because you do not have an instance of LinersTable, what you can do is declare it as a static function. I do not know how will this impact your code because you will need to do some corrections.